# Restrict TLS 1.1 and older to access Here Maps API

Tags: here-api, heremaps

As stated on this Release:
https://developer.here.com/blog/here-workspace-marketplace-2.4-release
Here API is now compatible with TLS 1.2 and onwards.

Is there a way to restrict access to the API to TLS 1.1 and older?

Some Applications not only require compatibility with 1.2, but they also require restriction to 1.1 and older

Answer (score 0):

From May 2019 onwards only TLSv1.2 and higher versions are supported by the Platform. The statement is correct.

I would really recommend to have a look for the recent release [2.19](https://developer.here.com/blog/here-workspace-marketplace-2.19-release)

As you can see in the [overview](https://developer.here.com/blog/topic/here-platform-release-announcements) we have monthly releases and improved the Platform a lot expecially within 2020.